# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (100,100,3) into shape (100,100)

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

```py
images = np.zeros((len(files),1,100,100))
for i, x in enumerate(files):
    im = Image.open(x)
    im = im.resize((100,100))
    images[i,0,:,:] = np.array(im, dtype=np.float32)/255.0
```

Here files are rgb files with `(360, 640, 3)` shape and `len(files)=15312` but the code is for processing grey images.  Anyone tell me, where to change the code to process my RGB images.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert image to gray

Fixed code

```
images = np.zeros((len(files),1,100,100)) 
for i, x in enumerate(files):
    im = Image.open(x)
    im = im.resize((100,100))
    im = im.convert('L')
    images[i,0,:,:] = np.asarray(im, dtype=np.float32)/255.0
```